# CSS Background Image Not Displaying

Tags: html, css, path, background-image

I have an HTML file with a subdirectory called `img` with an image called `debut_dark.png`. In my CSS file, I have:

```
body { 
    background: url(/img/debut_dark.png) repeat 0 0;
}
```

The HTML file has the body tag and does include the CSS file appropriately. I know for sure the CSS file is included properly as everything else is formatted properly.

The background image is not getting displayed, I am only seeing a white background. Any ideas how to fix this, or even how to debug it?

Comment: Check if image url is correct. Open developer tools and see network tab, your debut_dark.png should be listed there. Check if it was loaded at all

Comment: Are you sure about  image path and name?Check with firebug

Comment: If you want to debug something (HTML/JS/CSS) - you can always open some kind of developer tools available for all modern browsers (F12 is usually enough, but for FF you may need to install Firebug).

Comment: It appears that the image is not loaded. The img subdirectory is in the same directory as the html file. The image is in there. I am using `img/debut_dark.png` as the path, and it's not working.

Comment: @Darksky have you tried to use some dev tools? Also - what is path to your HTML file (that is important to know)?

Comment: Can you open the image directly in the browser when navigating to img/debut_dark.png ?

Comment: Try to remove the `repeat 0 0` part and put the images `width` and `height`.

Comment: Try this it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233529/pathing-from-in-subdomain/26632150#26632150

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to your CSS file path, I will suppose it is at the same directory with your HTML page, you have to change the `url` as follows:

```css
body { background: url(img/debut_dark.png) repeat 0 0; }
```

Comment: I did and I'm still seeing a white background.

Comment: @Darksky Where is your CSS file?

Comment: Got it. The path has to be relative to the CSS file (obviously). Thanks!

Comment: @darksky or the absolute path from the document root of your web server.

Comment: in my case, I already added the background-color:white to the input field. remove the background color then add your image

Answer (score 21):

You should use like this:

```
        body { 
            background: url("img/debut_dark.png") repeat 0 0;
        }

        body { 
            background: url("../img/debut_dark.png") repeat 0 0;
        }

        body { 
            background-image: url("../img/debut_dark.png") repeat 0 0;
        }
```

or try Inspecting CSS  Rules using Firefox Firebug tool.

Comment: I got it.. It had to be url("../img/debut_dark.png"). I just realised the path has to be relative to the CSS file not the HTML file (obviously).

Comment: ok. but @Darksky you marked right answer to semsem. i solved your problem  :(

Answer (score 11):

I know this doesn't address the exact case of the OP, but for others coming from Google don't forget to try `display: block;` based on the element type. I had the image in an `<i>`, but it wasn't appearing...

Comment: This helped me :)

Answer (score 7):

Make sure your body has a height, f.ex:

```
body { 
    background: url(/img/debut_dark.png) repeat;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the key. I had a code like this and did not work: `.legaltech-procedure .legaltech-proc-details-left span.jp
{
 display: block;
 background-image: url("/images/flags/1x1/jp.svg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 25px 25px;
}
` but then I added `min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;` and it displayed the image.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue. But it works properly for me

```
background: url(../img/debut_dark.png) repeat
```

Comment: For anyone who the previous answers did not help, this one works. I had the same problem since when creating the site locally, the browser assumes you are referencing from the partition's root directory. Adding two dots to the URL tells the browser that the file is in the root folder as the index.html file. Alternatively, add the entire path. Such as "D:/path_to_image/image.jpg"

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. For me it worked with:

```
  background: url("../img/green.jpg") no-repeat center bottom/cover;
  height: 100vh;
```

Answer (score 3):

Its always good to have these additional properties besides the

background-image:url('path') no-repeat 0 0;

1. set dimension to the element

   > width:x;
   >    height:y;
2. > background-size:100%

   - This property helps to fit the image to the above dimension that you define for an element.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a relative path in the URL. I think you made two folders in the root directory where your index.html resides. One is 'CSS' folder & another is 'img' folder.

Now, if you have to access 'img' folder in css files. So you have to go back once in root directory using "../" syntax. Then move to the 'img' folder using "../img" syntax. Then write the image name "../img/debut_dark.png".

```
body { 
    background: url("../img/debut_dark.png") repeat 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
body { 
        background: url("../img/debut_dark.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    }
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

inside `<link>` tag in your html file inside href of `<link>` tag put a dot(.)before the actual path

if the path of style sheet is /css/style.css then the reference will be as follows

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

then inside the .css file

put a double dot(..) before the actual path which the image stored it will be like this

```
body{background-image : url("../img/image.jpg");}
```

the above method worked for me

Comment: what does link stylesheet image stands for? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Answer (score 1):

I am using embedded CSS on a local computer. I put the atom.jpg file in the same folder as my html file, then this code worked:

```
background-image:url(atom.jpg);
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. It was getting blocked when I tried a full path to the file. When I put a copy in the working folder, it worked. Got the background image.

Answer (score 1):

```
background : url (/img.. )
```

NOTE: If you have your css in a different folder, ensure that you start the image path with THE FORWARD SLASH.

It worked for me. !

Comment: Been developing for about 10yrs - took me far too long to get to this haha

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `!important` syntax, it should work fine :

`background: url(/img/debut_dark.png) repeat 0 0 !important;`

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out that this attribute display image when the full location is provided in it. I simply uploaded that image on my server and linked the location of that image in the background-image:url("xxxxx.xxx"); attribute and it finally worked but if you guys don't have server then try to enter the complete location of the image in the attribute by going in property of that image. Although i was using this attribute in  tag of an HTML file but it will surely works on CSS file too. If that method didn't work then try to upload your image on internet like behance, facebook, instagram,etc and inspect the image and copy that location to your attribute.. Hope This will work

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, after i remove the repeat 0 0 part, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your path is correct then I think you don't have any element in you body section.
Just define the height of the body and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

In this Question we are going to describe how to use external css use for image calling

like: assets/images/laravelamit.jpg

then you have to go to assets/css/style.css and open and put

background: url(../images/laravelamit.jpg);

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing locally
Check if you are processing SCSS to CSS
Live sass compiler in VSCode

Answer (score 0):

Try To check the direction of the “/“ “\”….for me they were in the wrong direction

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem arose when I used short hand css code.

Example: shorthand - did NOT work

> ```
> background-image:url(photos/image.png) no-repeat center;
> ```

non shorthand - WORKED

> ```
> background-image:url(photos/image.png);
> background-repeat: no-repeat;
> background-position: center;
> ```

I hope this helps you. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Basically the problem is with file path.
The forward slash in the beginning of the url makes it look for the file at the root. Removing that, it will be a path relative to this css file - like this: 
`background-image: url(img/debut_dark.png);`

If you are using Atom, copying the project path of image sometimes includes forward slash in the copied path so be careful.

Comment: Do not vandalize your post. This may result in an [answer ban](//stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans). By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using vs code just try using
background:url("img/bimg.jpg")
instead of  background:url('img/bimg.jpg')
Mine worked at it
Nothing much I replaced ' with "

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this explanation may solve the question, including a sample code of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. I suggest you to edit your answer to add some code example, Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks!