# Pathing from ../ in subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, path

Lets say I create a subdomain :  http://subdomain.mydomain.com/

That was originally at this url : http://mydomain.com/subfolder/folder/

How would I fix pathing issues for
 **../** on http://subdomain.mydomain.com/

without a replacing code in .htaccess? is it possible?

Comment: Try explaining that one more time.  It's not exactly clear what you're asking.  What "pathing issues"?

Comment: In index.php of the subdomain I have '../javascript.js' that links to a file inside http://mydomain.com/subfolder/  '../' represents "Back one directory" - So then, it would be trying to go back a directory from the supposed root of the subdomain.

Comment: So you have broken links.  Fix them.  `mydomain.com/subdomain` and `subdomain.mydomain.com` are two entirely different sites, as far as a browser cares.

Comment: Sorry about the belated reply, however I had an unexpected crash and ended up forgetting/leaving the project alone.  Problem was that a subdomain is counted as an individual website.  I had put some thought into it. It would have been possible to create a class/function to request which subdomain the user created, and associated it with a path, probably putting it in a cell beside the subdomain associate to compare and set the new path.  I dont think it was possible with htaccess because a subdomain is considered a root and ../ would automatically thereby be considered invalid

Answer (score 1):

let say I have some masive structure like this.

[image]

Now in this case I want to do is in the css -> style -> loginCSS I have a css file named as login and I want to take that

ca_grain_texture.jpg and set it as a background of my login.html file so we see that our html files are in the main directory
and also our css folder is in main directory

so if i want to grab the grain jpg file from my login.css file. I have to do somthing like this.

e.g

```
body{
    background-image: url(../../../images/cs_grain_texture.jpg);
}
```

on writing ../ everytime it will jump one folder back similar to cd/ in command shell.

../ means it will go to loginCSS folder.

../../ means style folder.

../../../ means css which is the main directory.

I hope it helps understanding I understood this way and hope it clears your view.

Comment: This is an old question - I have not found a solution to this in over a year, however I haven't been looking hard enough.. the result I left it off at was basically that people were telling me the subdomain is counted as a root, so I would have to come up with some sort of tricky method to tell the server its not the root. I had though htaccess would have this potential.  and since i was using the method ../ it was impossible to do so. so I would have to do a possible SQL lookup as to which the user created, then associate and re-write using php probably with a compare function/class