# HTML CSS background image not loading

Tags: html, css, django

I have a background image `url('home1400.jpg')` from the `style.css` file. I have saved the image in the same folder as the `style.css` for debugging.

```
    /* ===== Home ====== */
    .sectionHome{
      width: 100%;
        min-height: 90vh;
        background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.3), rgba(0,0,0,0.3)), url('home1400.jpg'); 
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction:column ;
      }
    /* ===== end food Home ====== */
```

I checked that the `home.html` reads the `style.css` because if I change the `home1400.jpg` for any url with a picture in the internet, it loads the picture in the internet.

So I cannot see the image and I dont know why. I see in Chrome inspection that the image points to an static `url`. Is this the reason? Maybe my Django statics are wrongly set?

[image: Chrome inspection to image]

Any idea what may be going on? I have checked [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029277/css-background-image-not-displaying) but still not working.

Comment: Add your template and your style.css files.

Comment: where does stand your image about the folder where stands **style.css** ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus the image is in the same folder and location as the style.css to make it easy to debug. Once this works I will move it to another folder and update the filepath.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the unthinkable after 1+ hour of debugging.

I can see the image thumbnail in the file explorer but somehow the image was corrupted. I replaced it with other local file and it works just fine.

Comment: Please let me know if I should delete the question or leave it as testament to my clumsiness. Maybe other people find it useful.